Selenium error: Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Unable to parse remote response
Getting this error when trying to open browser on selenium 4.15
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Unable to parse remote response: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">

Unable to open browser with url: '' (Root cause: com.kms.katalon.core.exception.StepFailedException: Unable to open browser with url: ''
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.internal.WebUIKeywordMain.stepFailed(WebUIKeywordMain.groovy:64)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.internal.WebUIKeywordMain.runKeyword(WebUIKeywordMain.groovy:26)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.builtin.OpenBrowserKeyword.openBrowser(OpenBrowserKeyword.groovy:81)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.builtin.OpenBrowserKeyword.execute(OpenBrowserKeyword.groovy:67)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.keyword.internal.KeywordExecutor.executeKeywordForPlatform(KeywordExecutor.groovy:74)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.WebUiBuiltInKeywords.openBrowser(WebUiBuiltInKeywords.groovy:64)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.WebUiBuiltInKeywords$openBrowser.call(Unknown Source)
    at SSTC-18327_SSTC-18328_SSTC-18329_Offline_grading.run(SSTC-18327_SSTC-18328_SSTC-18329_Offline_grading:33)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.ScriptEngine.run(ScriptEngine.java:194)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.ScriptEngine.runScriptAsRawText(ScriptEngine.java:119)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.runScript(TestCaseExecutor.java:448)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.doExecute(TestCaseExecutor.java:439)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.processExecutionPhase(TestCaseExecutor.java:418)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.accessMainPhase(TestCaseExecutor.java:410)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.execute(TestCaseExecutor.java:285)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.common.CommonExecutor.accessTestCaseMainPhase(CommonExecutor.java:65)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestSuiteExecutor.accessTestSuiteMainPhase(TestSuiteExecutor.java:148)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestSuiteExecutor.execute(TestSuiteExecutor.java:106)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain.startTestSuite(TestCaseMain.java:187)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain$startTestSuite$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at TempTestSuite1718889648776.run(TempTestSuite1718889648776.groovy:35)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Unable to parse remote response: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">

The error is intermittent and occurs randomly not always on the same test case, I read updating version should help but it hasn't helped in my case

include initialization code.  You shouldn't be getting back HTML from the browser.  Right now the webdriver seems to be getting an HTML response from a wire protocol request.
Proxy maybe?
